# Loging in with information from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys everybody on stackoverflow has been such a help in getting my registration page working and safe I got the structure from a crappy tutorial and some guys/gals on here helped set me straight so I figured id pool your resources and see if we cant figure out my login page because low and behold the tutorial fell short once again..

here is the code for my registration page... It works great it saves information to the database and encrypts the passwords...

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
   $db =connect('******','******');
   if($db!=false)
{
   register($db);
   echo "User registered";
}

}

function connect($dbuser,$dbpassword)
{
    try{
        $db = new  PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=login',$dbuser,$dbpassword);
        return $db;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e;
        return false;}
}

function register($db)
{
    $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = shal($_POST['password']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['e_mail']);

    $query = "INSERT INTO members(username,password,email) values('".$user."','".$password."','".$email."')";
    try{
        $db->eginTransaction();
        $db->exec($query);
        $db->commit();
        echo "commit succesful";
    }catch(Exception $e){}
}




?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://localhost/projects/login/rigister/php" method="post">
username:<input type="text" name="username"/>
password:<input type="password" name="password"/>
email<input type="text" name="e_mail"/>
<input type="submit"/>

</form>


</body>
</html>
```

and here is the code that is not working for my login page.....

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
echo "WELCOME you are logged in";   
}

if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = shal1($_POST['password']);

$db = connect('******','******');
$eval = validate($db,$username,$password);
}
if($eval!=false)
{
    echo "Welcome ".$eval; 
    $_SESSION['username']=$eval;
    }


function connect($dbuser,$dbpassword)
{
    try{
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jsnow_login',    '*****' , '*****');
        return $db;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e;
        return false;}
}

function validate($db, $user,$password)
{
    $username=false;
    $query = "Select username,password FROM jsnow_members where username  ='".$username."' AND password = '".$password."'";
        try{
            $db->beginTransaction();
            $result = $db->query($query);

            foreach($result as $row)
            {
                $username = $row['username'];   
            }
            $db->commit();

            return $username;
        }catch(Exception $e){}
}



?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="http://vps8383.inmotionhosting.com/~jsnow/login.php">
username: <input type="text" name="username"/>
password: <input type="password" name="password"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</body>
</html>
```

...... the database name is jsnow_members and the fields are username,password,and email any help would be awesome and laymens terms are appriciated im definately a php/mysql rookie

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe this will be the problem:

```
function validate($db, $user,$password) {
    $username=false;
    $query = "Select username,password FROM jsnow_members where username  ='".$username."' AND password = '".$password."'";
```

Here you're querying the database for `username = false`. You've passed the username variable as `$user`, so you should change it to

```
$query = "Select username,password FROM jsnow_members where username  ='".$user."' AND password = '".$password."'";
```

Besides that, there's no need for transaction since you're not modifying any data.

EDIT: To further fix your problems, I've rewritten your `validate` function:

```
function validate($db, $user,$password) {
    $query = "Select username,password FROM jsnow_members where username  ='".$username."' AND password = '".$password."'";
    $stmt = $db->query($query);
    if ($stmt === false) return false;
    return $stmt->fetchColumn();
}
```

Comment: tried it out but still no messages are appearing from echo the only thing that is happening is that it is now displaying a username and a password in the url

Comment: anymore ideas on this issue?